# Short story where explorers searching the universe for Earth discover that humanity was wiped out by war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

I’ve been trying to find this short story for ages. I read it in a sci-fi anthology collection in 2005; it had a red/orange cover, and was definitely an older book, probably from the '60s. I don’t remember any of the other stories, except that one involved a polar setting.

The story referred to in the title follows the captain of a spaceship attempting to find Earth. Somehow, their navigation systems went awry so they are searching the galaxies planet-by-planet. The crew stays in hyper sleep during the journey.

They touch down on a barren, devastated, windswept planet and discover from reading a log book in a lighthouse that this is Earth. Humanity was wiped out in a war against another group “on that distant star”. One of the crew members kills himself after this realization, while the captain returns to the ship, intent on continuing the (now-pointless) search.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this story?

Comment: This question sounds similar to [this old (unanswered) question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139009/short-story-lost-starship-crew-in-suspended-animation-trying-to-return-to-earth).

Comment: *searching the galaxies planet-by-planet*  That would take one heck of a lot of time even if you had FTL (maybe longer than the Sun would survive), so are you sure about that ?

Comment: David, you’re completely right! We’re definitely describing the same story. A shame that question was never answered, though. At least I’m not the only one searching!